# Error when adding EntityFramework to project

Tags: entity-framework-4

When I installed VS2010 and created MVC3 project than I could add ADO.NET Entity Data Model without any problem.

Installed

- EF_JUNE_2011_CTP
- EFTools
- SQL Server developer tools Codename 'Juneau' and windows updates.

Now whenever try to add EDM get error as alert and unable to add it. For existing EMD when clicked I see XML as EDM.

Anyone tell me what to do?

```
Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.
Tracer.AssertTraceEvent(Boolean,System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType, 
Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.TraceId,System.String)'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdt/thread/adc028f7-b8ee-47c6-9e6f-b53ceb570769. There are some SxS issues with"Juneau" CTP3 and EFTools. It's recommended to install these on separate machines.

**Update:**
This is the rollback I suggested in the above link to get back to a 'working state' on your machine with the June 2011 entity designer update. It was confirmed by the OP. As mentioned above, Juneau CTP3 and the new EFTools package cannot be installed SxS due to a bug.

1. Uninstall both Juneau CTP3 and the Entity Framework designer update
2. Install Entity Framework designer update
3. This should get things working on your current machine. Unfortunately if you want to try out Juneau CTP3 you will have to install it on a separate machine from this one (a VM maybe) because of the conflicting issues with the EF 4.1 designer update.